# Why can't I use Array.prototype.find with String.prototype.startsWith as the filter?

Tags: javascript, arrays

This throws an error:

```
['hello'].find('helloworld'.startsWith);

Uncaught TypeError: String.prototype.startsWith called on null or undefined
at startsWith (<anonymous>)
at Array.find (<anonymous>)
at <anonymous>:1:11
```

But when wrapped in an arrow function, it works fine

```
['hello'].find(string => 'helloworld'.startsWith(string));

"hello"
```

Why is this?

Comment: Because `find()` expect a function as a argument

Comment: `'helloworld'.startsWith` is a function

Comment: The problem is the JavaScript runtime only sees `startsWith` without the context of `'helloworld'`.

Comment: `startsWith` is a method available of the `String` object prototype. When executed the literal `helloworld` is wrapped in a String object providing the prototype methods. When you pass `startsWith` directly in it looses the context of the object it came from. Internally its probably attempting to access `this` (or the native level equivalent) to get the string literal to check against. Which can be seen with `Object.getPrototypeOf('')`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you need not only the function, but also the bound object.

This could be achieved by using `thisArg` of [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```js
console.log(['hello'].find(String.prototype.startsWith, 'helloworld'));
```

or by binding the string to the function.

```js
console.log(['hello'].find(String.prototype.startsWith.bind('helloworld')));

// sloppy
console.log(['hello'].find(''.startsWith.bind('helloworld')));
```

**CAVEAT**

[`String#startsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) and [`String#endsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith) have a **second parameter** for an index.

The index is handed over of [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and works only on special circumstances, like for `startsWith` with an array with a single string (at index zero) for all other strings, it is likely not to work.

`endsWith` needs an index from the end of the array and it is dependent on the string length and index by using an array iterating method.

Comment: Any idea why it doesn't work with `endsWith`?

Comment: `helloworld` does not end with `hello`?

Comment: It doesn't work even if we use the whole string.
`['helloworld'].find(String.prototype.startsWith, 'helloworld')` outputs `'helloworld'`.
But if we replace `startsWith` with `endsWith`, it outputs `undefined` instead.

Comment: It produce the same output with SpiderMonkey (Firefox).
Maybe the wrong value is passed as the second argument to `endsWith`.

Comment: `String.prototype.endsWith = function() { console.log(JSON.stringify(arguments)) }` having the following output: `{"0":"helloworld","1":0,"2":["helloworld"]}`